# how to fix the error:Cannot read property 'mapmatching' of undefined

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I use mapbox-match.js locally without use http request to match the route on map . but I have problem in matching and the error message

> "Cannot read property `'mapmatching'` of undefined"

shown. how to solve this?

this is for map visualization with local host map. running http server, html and javascript. I use d3-js and mapbox to render set of coords as geojson data on a map to visualize a route

```
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <script src='MAPBOX/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
  <link href='MAPBOX/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <script src='mapbox.js-publisher-production/src/mapbox.js'></script>
  <script src='mapbox-match.js-master/src/match.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    function updateRoute(newCoords) {
      // Set the profile
      var profile = "driving";
      L.mapbox.mapmatching(Coords, profile);
    }

    L.mapbox.mapmatching(Coords, profile, function(error, layer) {

      layer.addTo(map);
      layer.setStyle({
        color: '#9a0202',
        weight: 4,
        opacity: 0.8
      });

      layer.addLayer({
        "id": "route",
        "type": "line",
        "source": {
          "type": "geojson",
          "data": {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {},
            "geometry": coords
          }
        },
        "layout": {
          "line-join": "round",
          "line-cap": "round"
        },
        "paint": {
          "line-color": "#33C9EB",
          "line-width": 3
        }

      });
    });
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

after debugging code the error shown "TypeError: Cannot read property 'mapmatching' of undefined"